# Убрать всё лишнее из строки

Tags: javascript

Надо убрать пробелы в начале и в конце строки, повторяющиеся пробелы в середине (оставить по одному) и всё кроме цифр, русских и английских букв любого регистра.

Чтобы из этого:

```
var str = '   aB,c D  e5//e а9_Б *   в ';
```

Получилось это:

```
var str = 'aBc D e5e а9Б в';
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let str = "   aB,c D  e5//e а9_Б *   в ";
str = str.trim()
 .replace(/[^\s\da-zа-я]/gi, "")
 .replace(/\s+/g, " ");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: забыл про ё и вызов trim должен быть последним `str.replace(/[^\s\da-zа-яё]/gi, "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim()`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const s = '   aB,c D  e5//e а9_Б *   в ';
console.log(s.replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim());
```

Comment: твой результат не соответствует результату указанному в вопросе

Comment: Сорри, неправильно прочитал вопрос. Не подумал про символы.